# How to transfer/upload data from s3 bucket to MinIO bucket given their end points and secret, access keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, data-transfer, minio

I plan to set up a Minio server on an Ec2 instance and upload data currently stored in my s3 bucket to Minio bucket via its client mc. I'm essentially trying to find Minio APIs that enable this transfer that is, directly between s3 bucket and Minio bucket given their end points and secret, access keys.
Are there any? Or is there a better way to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thoroughly following [MinIO documentation](https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-client-quickstart-guide.html), I was able to find a solution to this. Turns out it requires setting up a MinIo client mc and it will do the work for you.

To copy a folder recursively from MinIO cloud storage to Amazon S3 cloud storage with specified metadata.

```
mc cp --attr Cache-Control=max-age=90000, min- 
fresh=9000\;key1=value1\;key2=value2 --recursive 
play/mybucket/burningman2011/ s3/mybucket/
```